# How can i make an array of objects in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to define an `array` of objects in JavaScript. object with two properties first is a `text` and second is a `boolean`. that at first it is empty and then I add member in array one by one.

```
myarray = [
{"text1",true},
{"text2",false},
{"text3",false}
];
```

Comment: Post your coding attempt

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create an array and define its data like this:

```
var myarray = [];
myarray.push({ text: 'text1', boolean: true });
myarray.push({ text: 'text2', boolean: false});
myarray.push({ text: 'text3', boolean: false});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 var myArray = [text1,text2,text3];
  var objArray= [];
  for (let index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++) {
    var newItem = {};
    newItem = {
      name: myArray[index],
      value: true
    }
    objArray.push(newItem);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to define structure before, just add items

```
let myarray = [];
console.log(myarray);

// one by one
myarray.push({ text: 'text1', boolean: true });
console.log(myarray);

// more at once
myarray = myarray.concat(
    [
        { text: 'text2', boolean: false },
        { text: 'text3', boolean: false }
    ]
);
console.log(myarray);
```